# how to make regexp for passwordfield on beaneditform?

Tags: java, tapestry

i try to make regexp for passwordfield on beaneditform,but passwordfield don't recognizes regexep???any suggestion please???? :)

addUser.tml

```
<t:beaneditform t:id="newUser" exclude="id" reorder="userName,password,fullName,Gender,email,role">
..........................
<t:parameter t:name="password">
            <t:label t:for="password" />
            <t:passwordfield t:id="password" t:value="newUser.password" t:validate="required,regexp"/>
        </t:parameter>
.......................
</t:beaneditform>
```

addUser.properties

```
password-regexp=^[a-z0-9_]{3,15}$ 
password-regexp-message=password only alowed letters [a-z] numbers[0-9] and underscore
```

addUser.java:

```
@Persist
    @Property
    private User newUser;
```

Comment: Are you not getting the validation ... or are you getting a runtime exception? You solution looks good otherwise, though is your class name really "addUser" (traditionally Java class names are capitalized, so this looks odd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vlad said, i also think in tapestry there is no integrated regexp check in the markup, see in this [link](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry4/UsersGuide/validation.html) at the end the supported validators(But maybe there is in the version you are ussing, not really sure about that).

Maybe you could try somehow to use the onValidate lifeCycle event handler, to validate that field against a wrong input.

```
@Component
private Form yourForm;

@Property
private String inputFromField;

public void onValidate() {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");//Alpha numeric regexp
        Matcher m = p.matcher(inputFromField); 
        if(m.find()) {
          yourForm.recordError(inputFromField,messages.get("This field can only contain letters and numbers"));
        }            
}
```

Anyway, Im sure there is more than one way of how to do this, but this is just an example. 
I didnt compile and try it, but im pretty sure this is the one of the ways that can be done. If you need more help, have a look at this page: http://www.packtpub.com/article/user-input-validation-in-tapestry-5

Remember to add the  tag to your form.

**Update**

I was wrong when i said that it is not possible to use the regexp directly in the markup.
After having a look at Heanning's link, i saw that there is the possibility of using the regexp directly as you planned.
Example:

```
<t:textfield value="otherfield" validate="regexp=^a-z+$" />
```

I would recommend you to have a look at the link he said, it is well explained there(For Tapestry 5): http://tapestry.apache.org/forms-and-validation.html

Comment: No, in Tapestry 5.0 and after, there is a regexp validator - see the [Validation section in the docs](http://tapestry.apache.org/forms-and-validation.html), or in the secord link you provided.

Comment: @Henning Those are great news. I just rode a bit that link and updated my answer, so he also has the option of using a catalog for the regxp's. Anyway great link (1+ in comment)

Comment: i try to provide regexp for passwordfield not for textfield
<t:passwordfield t:id="password" t:value="newUser.password" t:validate="required,regexp"/>

Comment: @dusmanka Do, have a try passwordfield and textfield are almost the same. If it works for one, should work for the other.

Answer (score 0):

You use `t:id="newUser"` but your properties file is `addUser.properties`. Are you sure tapestry knows where to look for `password-regexp`?

Comment: tapesty knows where to look because of i alredy work with regexp for email,userName...this for userName and email works ok!